# Is it possible to check if an object implements a trait at runtime?

Tags: rust

```
trait Actor{
    fn actor(&self);
}
trait Health{
    fn health(&self);
}
struct Plant;
impl Actor for Plant{
    fn actor(&self){
        println!("Plant Actor");
    }
}
struct Monster{
    health: f32
}
impl Actor for Monster{
    fn actor(&self){
        println!("Monster Actor");
    }
}
impl Health for Monster{
    fn health(&self){
        println!("Health: {}",self.health);
    }
}
fn main() {
    let plant = Box::new(Plant);
    let monster = Box::new(Monster{health: 100f32});

    let mut actors : Vec<Box<Actor>> = Vec::new();
    actors.push(plant);
    actors.push(monster);

    for a in &actors{
        a.actor();
        /* Would this be possible?
        let health = a.get_trait_object::<Health>();
        match health{
            Some(h) => {h.health();},
            None => {println!("Has no Health trait");}
        }
        */
    }
}
```

I am wondering if something like this could be possible?

```
let health = a.get_trait_object::<Health>();
match health{
    Some(h) => {h.health();},
    None => {println!("Has no Health trait");}
}
```

Comment: There is currently a set of RFCs toward getting downcasting (in one way or another) in Rust. It will be possible one day, but not for now.

Answer (score 16):

It is not possible to do this in Rust at present, nor is it likely to ever become possible; it is, however, possible to construct similar abstractions as part of your trait:

```rust
trait Actor {
    fn health(&self) -> Option<&dyn Health>;
}

trait Health { }

impl Actor for Monster {
    fn health(&self) -> Option<&dyn Health> { Some(self) }
}

impl Health for Monster { }

impl Actor for Plant {
    fn health(&self) -> Option<&dyn Health> { None }
}
```

Rust is expected to get negative bounds at some point; when that comes, you’ll be able to have something like this:

```rust
trait MaybeImplements<Trait: ?Sized> {
    fn as_trait_ref(&self) -> Option<&Trait>;
}

macro_rules! impl_maybe_implements {
    ($trait_:ident) => {
        impl<T: $trait_> MaybeImplements<dyn $trait_> for T {
            fn as_trait_ref(&self) -> Option<&dyn $trait_> {
                Some(self)
            }
        }

        impl<T: !$trait_> MaybeImplements<dyn $trait_> for T {
            fn as_trait_ref(&self) -> Option<&dyn $trait_> {
                None
            }
        }
    }
}

impl_maybe_implements!(Health);

trait Actor: MaybeImplements<dyn Health> {
}

let health: Option<&dyn Health> = actor.as_trait_ref();
```

This will reduce the boilerplate from every implementation of a trait to just one per trait, but that stage is not yet upon us. Still, you could take the middle ground of the two approaches:

```rust
trait MaybeImplements<Trait: ?Sized> {
    fn as_trait_ref(&self) -> Option<&Trait>;
}

macro_rules! register_impl {
    ($trait_:ident for $ty:ty) => {
        impl MaybeImplements<dyn $trait_> for $ty {
            fn as_trait_ref(&self) -> Option<dyn $trait_> {
                Some(self)
            }
        }
    }

    (!$trait_:ident for $ty:ty) => {
        impl MaybeImplements<dyn $trait_> for $ty {
            fn as_trait_ref(&self) -> Option<dyn $trait_> {
                None
            }
        }
    }
}

register_impl!(Health for Monster);
register_impl!(!Health for Plant);
```

Play around with different ways of handling it until you find something you like! The possibilities are limitless! <sub><sup>(Because Rust is Turing‐complete.)</sup></sub>

Comment: This doesn't compile (probably outdated)

Comment: Updated. When I wrote this answer, trait object types were spelled `Trait`; since then, it’s moved to `dyn Trait`. The old syntax still works if your crate uses the 2015 edition, but the new syntax must be used if your crate uses the 2021 edition, which you probably are now.

Comment: I'm not sure Rust will ever get negative bounds, but it'll probably get specialization at some point.

Answer (score 10):

As of 1.0, no.  Rust doesn't provide any dynamic downcasting support, with the exception of `Any`; however, that only allows you to downcast to a value's specific concrete type, not to arbitrary traits that said concrete type implements.

I *believe* you could implement such casting manually, but that would require unsafe code that would be easy to get wrong; not the sort of thing I want to try and summarise in an SO answer.

Comment: Each struct-trait pair have creates a custom vtable. To construct a dyn Trait, you'd need to know the location of the vtable in order to append it to a thin (data) pointer. If anyone _needs_ to do this, they should check out the ptr_metadata feature.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to check if an object implements a specific trait at runtime.
 If you know the concrete type implementing a trait that needs to be tested for, we can use downcasting to get that concrete type through runtime reflection (since 2018).

```
trait Actor {
    fn actor(&self);
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

trait Health {
    fn health(&self);
}

struct Plant;

impl Actor for Plant {
    fn actor(&self) {
        println!("Plant Actor");
    }
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

struct Monster {
    health: f32,
}

impl Actor for Monster {
    fn actor(&self) {
        println!("Monster Actor");
    }
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

impl Health for Monster {
    fn health(&self) {
        println!("Health: {}", self.health);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let plant = Box::new(Plant);
    let monster = Box::new(Monster { health: 100f32 });

    let mut actors: Vec<Box<dyn Actor>> = Vec::new();
    actors.push(plant);
    actors.push(monster);

    for a in &actors {
        if let Some(Monster { health, .. }) = (**a).as_any().downcast_ref::<Monster>() {
            println!("is a monster with health {health}");
        } else {
            println!("is a plant");
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=3f4022259867975722bdaf230da9dcf0)

Comment: Basically trait Health is unused here. Why you included it?

Comment: @Misiek That's right - that would only make sense if other characters came into play whose `health` would be defined differently. I simplified it for the case that the `Health` trait is defined the same for all characters.