# What is the alternative of downcasting a trait object in this situation?

Tags: rust, game-development

I have a `Companion` trait that encompasses a base trait for Components such as `Health`. I store a list of `Companion` using trait objects because all companions must at least implement the `Companion` trait. However not all companions will use the subtype `Health` trait.

Now the `heal` command only accepts a list of `Health` traits, so I need to filter out, remap and downcast all the base `Companion` traits so that it supports the `Health` traits.

I understand this is bad design. How can I implement the same behavior without having to downcast the trait objects to a specific component? Note: I cannot have a large struct which includes all the subtypes into one type.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
type CompanionId = Uuid;

fn main() {
    let mut companion_storage: HashMap<CompanionId, Box<dyn Companion>> = HashMap::new();
    let companion_id: CompanionId = Uuid::new_v4();
    companion_storage.insert(
        companion_id,
        Box::new(Cheetah {
            ...
        }),
    );
    let mut player = Player {
        ...,
        companions: Vec::new(),
    };
    player.companions.push(companion_id);

    'GameLoop: loop {
        let input = poll_input().trim().to_lowercase();

        match input.as_str() {
            // TODO: Extract healing component here.
            "heal" => heal_command(companion_id, companion_storage.into_iter().filter(|(companion_id, companion)| {
                // QUESTION: How do I filter out Companions without the Health trait here so they can automatically be downcasted and mapped?
            }).collect()),
            "q" => {
                break 'GameLoop;
            }
            "s" => {
                status_command(&player, &companion_storage); // SAME PROBLEM HERE
            }
            _ => println!("Unknown command"),
        }
    }
}

struct Player {
    id: u8,
    name: String,
    companions: Vec<CompanionId>,
}

trait Companion {
    ...
}

trait Health: Companion {
   ...
}

trait Status: Health {}

struct Cheetah {
    id: CompanionId,
    name: String,
    current_health: f32,
    max_health: f32,
}

impl Companion for Cheetah {
    ...
}

impl Health for Cheetah {
    ...
}

fn heal_command(
    companion_id: CompanionId,
    companion_storage: &mut HashMap<CompanionId, Box<dyn Health>>,
) {
    let companion = companion_storage.get_mut(&companion_id).unwrap();

    companion.heal_max();

    println!("Healed to max.");
}

fn status_command(player: &Player, companion_storage: &mut HashMap<CompanionId, Box<dyn Status>>) {
    println!("Status for {}: ", player.name);
    println!("===============================");
    print!("Companions: ");
    for companion_id in &player.companions {
        let companion = companion_storage.get(companion_id).unwrap();

        print!(
            "{} [{}/{}], ",
            companion.name(),
            companion.health(),
            companion.max_health()
        );
    }
    println!();
    println!("===============================");
}
```

Is this code a better alternative?

```
type CompanionId = Uuid;

fn main() {
    let mut companion_storage: HashMap<CompanionId, Companion> = HashMap::new();
    let companion_id: CompanionId = Uuid::new_v4();
    companion_storage.insert(
        companion_id,
        Companion {
            id: companion_id,
            name: "Cheetah".to_string(),
            health: Some(Box::new(RegularHealth {
                current_health: 50.0,
                max_health: 50.0,
            })),
        },
    );
    let mut player = Player {
        id: 0,
        name: "FyiaR".to_string(),
        companions: Vec::new(),
    };
    player.companions.push(companion_id);

    'GameLoop: loop {
        let input = poll_input().trim().to_lowercase();

         match input.as_str() {
            // TODO: Extract healing component here.
            "heal" => {
                let companion = companion_storage.get_mut(&companion_id).unwrap();

                match companion.health_mut() {
                    None => {
                        println!("The selected companion doesn't have health associated with it.");
                    }
                    Some(health) => {
                        heal_command(health);

                        println!("{} was healed to max.", companion.name);
                    }
                }
            }
            "q" => {
                break 'GameLoop;
            }
            "s" => {
                status_command(&player, &companion_storage); // SAME PROBLEM HERE
            }
            _ => println!("Unknown command"),
        }
    }
}

struct Player {
    id: u8,
    name: String,
    companions: Vec<CompanionId>,
}

struct Companion {
    id: CompanionId,
    name: String,
    health: Option<Box<dyn Health>>,
}

struct RegularHealth {
    current_health: f32,
    max_health: f32,
}

trait Health {
    ...
}

impl Companion {
    fn health_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut dyn Health> {
        match self.health.as_mut() {
            None => None,
            Some(health) => Some(health.as_mut()),
        }
    }

    fn health(&self) -> Option<&dyn Health> {
        match self.health.as_ref() {
            None => None,
            Some(health) => Some(health.as_ref()),
        }
    }
}

impl Health for RegularHealth {
    ...
}

fn heal_command(health: &mut dyn Health) {
    health.heal_max();
}

fn status_command(player: &Player, companion_storage: &HashMap<CompanionId, Companion>) {
    println!("Status for {}: ", player.name);
    println!("===============================");
    print!("Companions: ");
    for companion_id in &player.companions {
        let companion = companion_storage.get(companion_id).unwrap();

        match companion.health.as_ref() {
            None => {}
            Some(health) => {
                print!(
                    "{} [{}/{}], ",
                    companion.name,
                    health.health(),
                    health.max_health()
                );
            }
        }
    }
    println!();
    println!("===============================");
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is a bad design? This question, as currently worded, is opinion-based and inappropriate for SO. If you have _concrete_ points you want to improve, it may suit here. But please describe exactly what is verbose/inefficient/etc. with the current design.

Comment: In order to downcast, I would need to change the type for the trait object to be Any and for every function that accepts a certain downcasted trait, I would need to call .downcast_ref on the "Any" trait object inside a map and also do error handling to ensure that the subtype matches the parameter. I am looking for a better approach on binding a trait type to a function that doesn't involve downcasting.

Comment: would be nice if you had added a mre instead of all your code

Comment: Could you have a health type method for Companion that returns a value indicating whether the companion is eligible for healing under the current circumstances? Then you could also account for temporary modifiers like buffs/debuffs etc

Comment: @MeetTitan I updated the main post. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Maybe I would add to `Companion` a member `fn health(&mut self) -> Option<&mut dyn Health> { None }` and override in types that do need it to just return `Some(self)`.

Comment: you can try taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274091/is-it-possible-to-check-if-an-object-implements-a-trait-at-runtime. It has no accepted answer but I believe the proposed approaches are still the best the language can offer

Comment: You might want to look into the Entity-Component-System pattern and associated [crates](https://crates.io/search?page=1&per_page=10&q=entity component system).

Comment: @rodrigo that's a good suggestion. It makes the interface cleaner as I don't have to constantly unbox and box.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella that was a good read. Rust really pushes you to write good code and I love it especially coming from C++. There are a lot of patterns and idioms I am learning that is helping me get rid of the strict OOP mindset.

Comment: @Jmb I realized that I am accidentally writing a code that is very similar to entity component system. But since I am writing this project as means to learn Rust, I am probably going to skip adding ECS. But in actual projects, I will definitely use it.